# MySQL get relations users by one query from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to get list of "friends" from my tables. I have a two tables, one where I store users list, and second one where I store relations with this users. I add on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/043fe1/2) example schemas. I need to fetch all "friends" for specified user id:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_users
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55));

INSERT INTO tbl_users
    (`id`, `name`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'John', '111'),
    (2, 'Derrik', '222'),
    (3, 'Nikolas', '333'),
    (4, 'Hellen', '444'),
    (5, 'Jack', '555');

CREATE TABLE tbl_relations
    (`id` int, `user_id` int, `following_id` int);

INSERT INTO tbl_relations
    (`id`, `user_id`, `following_id`)
VALUES
    (1, '1', '2'),
    (2, '1', '3'),
    (3, '1', '4'),
    (4, '2', '1'),
    (5, '4', '1');
```

Yes, I can do two queries and then compare it, but I thing this should work with one.

Result expected: if specified user id = 1, result should be get 2,4 user

Thx.

Comment: use join for getting value from both table in one query.

Comment: `join` the two tables with primary and foregin key

Comment: `SELECT * 
FROM tbl_users as u
join tbl_relations as r on r.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id = 1`

Comment: Didn't saw his comment while I'm posted it.

Comment: I'm update Result expected

Comment: @S.I I think should be more select in this query, pls check update

Comment: All you really need is to read through this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp ;)

Comment: @iSS Likewise, read through this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry Ah, didn't know :) But it is a good starting point anyway :) I don't "gospelize" that thing. Besides, it's 40% better formatted than the official documentation :D

Answer (score 0):

If the table

1. users
2. relations

The two tables must have columns that have the same value. If the columns is `user_id` so

`SELECT * from users,relations WHERE users.user_id = relations.user_id;`

I hope this answer can help you :)

Comment: its not what I expected. This is on example

Comment: Please beware, that this does the crossjoin. It is fine when there are 100 users, it's not fine when there are 100 000 users!

Comment: @iSS u mean, need another struct of this?

Comment: As @Blinkydamo wrote: `SELECT * FROM users 
 JOIN relations ON \`relations\`.\`user_id\` = \`users\`.\`id\` 
 WHERE \`users\`.\`id\` = 1;` You join two tables and retrieve only the data you need the right way.

Comment: We tend to discourage comma-style joins around here (seeing as they were effectively deprecated back in the 1990s)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT tbl_users.* 

FROM tbl_users

INNER JOIN tbl_relations ON tbl_relations.user_id = tbl_users.id
```

[More about join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm)

Answer (score 0):

"Result expected: if specified user id = 1, result should be get 2,4 user"

```
SELECT x.following_id reciprocations
  FROM tbl_relations x 
  JOIN tbl_relations y 
    ON y.user_id = x.following_id 
   AND y.following_id = x.user_id 
 WHERE x.user_id = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

This should return 2,3 for user id 1

```
SELECT id FROM tbl_relations 
WHERE user_id = 1 AND id != user_id;
```

To get the friends instead of their ids use

```
SELECT * from tbl_users WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tbl_relations 
WHERE user_id = 1 AND id != user_id);
```

Comment: But this gets only who user 1 followed, but not relations with user 1 with user 2, and user 4